# Unpivot in SQL Server with where clause

Tags: sql-server, union, where-clause, unpivot

I have table [diameter, modulus, number of teeth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5SZHL.png)

Step 1: I choose diameter (column d, mm)

Step 2: I must choose two rows from table and transpose into two columns [number of teeth: z, modulus: m, mm] without value "0"

For example: i am in need for using UnPivot in SQL for getting the rows converted in columns, but not able to do so with my unpivot query:

```
SELECT NewColumn1
FROM tableTmp    
UNPIVOT (NewColumn1 FOR allcols IN ([n2],[n3],[n4],[n5])) up1 // and where n1 = 0

UNION All

SELECT NewColumn2
FROM tableTmp 
UNPIVOT (NewColumn2 FOR allcols IN ([n2],[n3],[n4],[n5]) ) up2 // and where n1 = 6
```

Any help would be appreciated, i'm stuck and theres is not that much info on the web, thanks!

Comment: What do you mean "not able to do so"? Are you getting an error or not getting the results you expect?

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same answer. Although this is 4 years old, what you should do is replace your tableTmp in both queries with a select statement on tableTmp with the necessary where clause added.

Comment: Can you add a code example with the changes made?